# Custom TileProvider with Polygon in Android maps

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay, polygon

I'm having problems drawing a polygon on Android map.
The problem is that I have TileOverlays so the polygon is kinda under the overlays.

I'm drawing a polygon on GoogleMap like this:

```
map.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions().add(points).strokeColor(Color.RED).strokeWidth(3f));
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(points[0], 18));
```

I can see the polygon before the tiles are starting to load but then it's gone. I would like to achieve that the polygon is drawn over the TileProvider.

I have a custom TileProvider which does three layers: cached layer, custom map layer and data layer which is partly transparent.

When map loads, I create all three layers:

```
cacheLayer = map.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(addCache()));
mapLayer = map.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(addMap()));
dataLayer = map.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(addData()));
```

How could I achieve that the polygon is above them all? Or at least above the map layer? Should I create another overlay just for the polygon? If so, how can I draw a polygon on the TileProvider? If that is possible, I could just draw it on the dataLayer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh well, the solution is pretty simple, if anyone else will have the problem in the future:

```
cacheLayer = map.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(addCache()).zIndex(1));
mapLayer = map.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(addMap()).zIndex(2));
dataLayer = map.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(addData()).zIndex(3));
```

And for the polygon:

```
map.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions().add(points).strokeColor(Color.RED).strokeWidth(3f).zIndex(4));
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(points[0], 18));
```