# Custom tile provider for polygon in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, polygons

I'm trying do a Custom `TileProvider` with Polygon too. But I don't know if I am in the right way. In fact I get my Polygon with the `getTileUrl` like this :

```
TileProvider tileProvider = new UrlTileProvider(256, 256) {

    @Override
    public synchronized URL getTileUrl(int x, int y, int zoom) {

        int reversedY = (1 << zoom) - y - 1;

        tt = true;

        x_tile=x;
        y_tile=reversedY;
        z_tile=zoom;


        Observable<Algorithm> algorithmObs = Observable.from(algorithm);
        Observable<List<Tuple<org.geojson.Polygon, Integer>>> geometriesObs = Observable
                .from(algorithm)
                .concatMap(algo -> algorithmService.getLatestVectorizedData(algorithm.getParcelle().getIndex(), algorithm.getIndex()))
                .map(VectorizedDataDto::getIndex)
                .concatMap(id -> algorithmService.getTiledVectorizedGeometries(algorithm.getIdAnalysedData(), 4,zoom,x,reversedY))
                .map(VectorizedGeometriesDto::geometriesWithColor);

        Observable
                .zip(algorithmObs, geometriesObs, Tuple::new)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(this::onSuccessGetVectorizedGeometrie);


        return null;
    }

    private void onSuccessGetVectorizedGeometrie(Tuple<Algorithm, List<Tuple<org.geojson.Polygon, Integer>>> tuple) {
        Algorithm algorithm = tuple.x;
        List<Tuple<org.geojson.Polygon, Integer>> geometriesWithColor = tuple.y;

        //algorithm.setParcelle(currentParcelle);

        algorithm.setPolygonsWithColor(geometriesWithColor);

        algorithm.setX_tile(x_tile);
        algorithm.setY_tile(y_tile);
        algorithm.setZ_tile(z_tile);
        algorithm.setPolygon(geometriesWithColor.toString());
        algorithm.save();


        showTiledPolygon();
    }

    public void showTiledPolygon(){

        for (Tuple<org.geojson.Polygon, Integer> algorithmPolygonWithColor : algorithm.getPolygonsWithColor()) {
            polygon = googleMap
                    .addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
                                    .addAll(PolygonHelper.getBorder(algorithmPolygonWithColor.x))
                                    .fillColor(algorithmPolygonWithColor.y)
                                    .strokeColor(0xff000000)
                                    .strokeWidth(3)
                            //.strokeColor(algorithmPolygonWithColor.y)
                            //.strokeWidth(0)
                    );

            algorithmPolygons.add(polygon);

        }

        mapProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


    }

};
```

It works, but I don't like my method because there is no cache, so I have to remove all polygons and to recall them at every zoom event.

Is there a better method for a custom tile provider with polygon ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Check this related [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34875340/custom-tileprovider-with-polygon-in-android-maps), I think it can give you an idea about how to add custom Tile Provider in android

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my problem isn't to add the custom tile Provider, but how to improve it. Indeed at the base, the tileprovider is supposed to work to display photos , so I would like to know how to change it to display polygons effectively. As I said above , my code works but I wanted to know if there was a way to improve it, to manage the cache for example :)